# how to detect some "$#%@*&$!" type characters from the String in php?

Tags: php

I have an Username input filed . if i want to detect some characters which is in an array like this `$array = array('#','%','^')`  so Is there any built in function in php for that ? which will Take an Array and return true or false .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[array_intersect](http://www.php.net/array_intersect) may help you - e.g.

```
$array = array('#','%','^');

if(array_intersect(str_split($username), $array)) {
    echo "Found";
} else {
    echo "Not Found";
}
```

Comment: Thanks .. just what i want ... @Chris Wheeler

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be:

```
if (str_replace($array, '', $username) != $username) {
  do something;
}
```

You can write your own function of course:

```
function contains_unallowed($array = ['#', '%', '^']) {
  return str_replace($array, '', $username) != $username;
}
```

It takes an array of characters as optional parameter and returns true or false. If it doesn't work, please replace the square braces `[]` with `array()`.

Comment: Thanks a Lot! .. it's working too .. and [] means an Array in php5.5+ right ?

Comment: Yes, exactly, it's a new feature.